# 辞書型の戻り値の記述について

Tags: python

以下に示す、戻り値に関する記述の意味が分かりません。

```py
return {k: v for k, v in balance.items()
        if isinstance(v, str) and float(v)}
```

リスト内包表記を参考に、自分なりに、以下の記述と同等表現と考えたのですが合ってますか。

```py
return{}
for k, v in balance.item():
    if (isinstance(v, str) and float(v)):
       .setdefault(k, v)
```

コードの全体像は下記のとおりです。

```
def balance(self):
    endpoint = self.url + '/api/accounts/balance'
    return self._request(endpoint=endpoint)

@property
    def position(self):
    balance = self.balance()
    return {k: v for k, v in balance.items()
            if isinstance(v, str) and float(v)}
```

※上記コードは [#12 Python×ビットコイン自動売買 | クラスを作成してコードを読みやすくしよう！](https://tech-diary.net/create-coincheck-class-object/) で紹介されているコードです。

Answer (score 1):

> リスト内包表記を参考に、自分なりに、以下の記述と同等表現と考えたのですが合ってますか。

実際に実行してみると判りますが、`.setdefault(k, v)` の部分で syntax error になります。syntax error を修正したとしても、最初に `return{}` としてしまっているので `Coincheck.position` property は常に empty dict(空(カラ)の辞書)を返す事になります。

以下は動作チェック用の stub code になります。

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
  import json
  from pprint import pprint

  cc = Coincheck('a', 'b')

  # 取引所APIドキュメント|仮想通貨取引所のCoincheck(コインチェック)
  # https://coincheck.com/ja/documents/exchange/api#account-balance
  cc.balance = lambda: json.loads('''
    {
      "success": true,
      "jpy": "0.8401",
      "btc": "7.75052654",
      "jpy_reserved": "3000.0",
      "btc_reserved": "3.5002",
      "jpy_lend_in_use": "0",
      "btc_lend_in_use": "0.3",
      "jpy_lent": "0",
      "btc_lent": "1.2",
      "jpy_debt": "0",
      "btc_debt": "0"
    }''')

  print('Original:')  
  pprint(cc.position)

  # replace Coincheck.position property
  def myposition(self):
    balance = self.balance()
    dic = {}
    for k, v in balance.items():
      if isinstance(v, str):
        try:
          if float(v): dic[k] = v
        except ValueError:
          continue

    return dic
  
  Coincheck.position = property(myposition)

  print('Replaced:')  
  pprint(cc.position)

# 実行結果
Original:
{'btc': '7.75052654',
 'btc_lend_in_use': '0.3',
 'btc_lent': '1.2',
 'btc_reserved': '3.5002',
 'jpy': '0.8401',
 'jpy_reserved': '3000.0'}

Replaced:
{'btc': '7.75052654',
 'btc_lend_in_use': '0.3',
 'btc_lent': '1.2',
 'btc_reserved': '3.5002',
 'jpy': '0.8401',
 'jpy_reserved': '3000.0'}
```

例外処理を行っているのは、`float()` は `ValueError` を発生させる場合があるからです。例えば、

```py
  cc.balance = lambda: {
    'a': '1.0', 'b': '2.0', 'c': '3.0c', 'd': 4.0
  }
```

として元のコードを実行すると、以下の様にエラーが発生します。

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "coin_check.py", line 74, in <module>
    print(f'Original: {cc.position}')
  File "coin_check.py", line 61, in position
    return {k: v for k, v in balance.items()
  File "coin_check.py", line 62, in <dictcomp>
    if isinstance(v, str) and float(v)}
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3.0c'
```

※ API ドキュメントを読む限り `ValueError` が発生する事はなさそうなので上記の例外処理は不要かもしれません。

Comment: すなわち、他の表現であればどのように記述するのが正しいのでしょうか。
また、`return {k: v for k, v in balance.items()if isinstance(v, str) and float(v)}`このコードの意味するものはどのようなことでしょうか。

Comment: 「どのように記述するのが正しいのでしょうか」、myposition 関数の中身がそれに当たります。「コードの意味するものはどのようなことでしょうか」、元のコードを読む限り、API コールのレスポンス（「残高」情報)から response status(`"success": true`) と「ゼロ値」(上記のコードでは `"jpy_lend_in_use"`, `"jpy_lent"`, `"jpy_debt"`, `"btc_debt"`)を削除しています。その意味(意義)については元のコードを書いた人に聞いてみなければ確かな事は判りませんけれども。

Comment: @milk 辞書内包表記の展開のみ考えれば, 一時変数用意し(ここでは `dic`), `for`ループで追加 ＆ `if`文で条件判断, 結果のオブジェクト(`dic`)を返す … という感じ

Answer (score 1):

`return`の後の式はリスト内包表記では無く、[5.5. 辞書型 (dictionary)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)で述べられている「辞書内包表現」という物です。

> さらに、辞書内包表現を使って、任意のキーと値のペアから辞書を作れます:
>
> ```
> >>> {x: x**2 for x in (2, 4, 6)}
> {2: 4, 4: 16, 6: 36}
> ```

他にも「集合内包表記」と言う物もあります。これらはリスト内包表記の親戚みたいな物で、リストの代わりに辞書(dict)または集合(set)を作る事になります。

内包表記を使わずに、かつ、ifもforの外側に展開した場合は、次のようになります。

```
data = {}
for k, v in balance.items():
    if isinstance(v, str) and float(v):
        data[k] = v
return data
```